# Impedance matching of an antenna with a cable

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching

This is sort of a conceptual question.
Suppose I have an antenna that is connected to a PCB via a 50 Ohm coaxial cable and a U.FL connector which is fed by some 50 Ohm PCB trace. Take [this antenna](https://www.taoglas.com/images/product_images/original_images/TAOGLAS%20-%20Flexible%20PCB%20Antenna%20Application%20Note_V2.pdf) for example.

Putting this antenna into an enclosure or really any other environment than that in the datasheet will change its frequency response and its S11, right? Is it possible to account for this using a matching network at the PCB connector?

Because in my head, the matching network would just match for the 50 Ohm transmission line, which is the antenna's cable, and therefore won't have the desired effect. Is this assumption correct?

On the other hand, could the cable be considered as part of the antenna, meaning the matching network will be effective?